# Is it legal to install one copy of Final Cut Pro X on six different Macs owned by six different people?

Tags: mac-appstore, license

I am wondering if it is legal and/or possible to buy a copy of Final Cut Pro X and then share the disk and the cost with five other people?

Comment: Can't see a reason to downvote this...

Comment: @MaxRied There's a good reason: it's blatantly, obviously illegal. This sort of action is why copyright violation is generally referred to as theft: because this is simple theft.

Comment: This is the first question I've wanted to vote both up and down. Up because it's a well-written, straightforward question. Down because the proposed action is obviously illegal.

Comment: AFAIK in Germany this isn't against Apple EULA. You are allowed to install it on every computer under your control. From my interpretation if you are the admin of a few PRIVATE computers this actually could be ok.

Answer (score 8):

No. This would violate the license agreement between you and Apple when you purchase the software.

Second, there is no such thing as an installation DVD for Final Cut Pro X. You would have to purchase it as a download and install and register it through the Mac App Store, and I don't think you would be able to use your single Mac App Store log-in account on six computers owned by six different people who are not family members of yours.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda tricky to answer, because questions of legality are highly dependent on your location.  Of course, it's entirely possible that you live in Afghanistan or a small and hitherto unknown spit of land in the middle of a vast ocean without any recognised legal system, or perhaps you roam the skies forever outside the jurisdiction of any sovreign state, occassionaly touching down in airports around the world to wash your underwear in the restrooms, but I'm going to go out on a limb and imagine that you live in, and are therefore bound by the laws of, The U S of A. (God bless)

So, no.

[You can't](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewEula?id=424389933).

:)

Comment: Even if he did live in one of the [few nations not bound by the Berne Convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_parties_to_international_copyright_agreements), Apple doesn't do business in any of them. He'd've had to have purchased his copy of FCP in a nation with a modern and compatible copyright regime, and his purchase would, at least to some extent, be bound by *those* laws. Of course, if he's living in Cambodia, he probably has *other concerns* and isn't terribly worried about copyright infringement.